# Implementing "Balanced Random Forest" in h2o

Tags: random-forest, unbalanced-classes, h2o

Currently having problems with (very) imbalanced classes in a dataset that I am trying to run binary classification on. Looking at this UC Berkeley article (http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/666.pdf), I would like to try using a "Balanced Random Forest" (using `h2o flow` UI). From the paper:

> Random forest inspired us to ensemble trees induced from balanced
>   down-sampled data. The Balanced Random Forest (BRF) algorithm is shown
>   below:
>
> 1. For each iteration in random forest, draw a bootstrap sample from the minority class. Randomly draw the **same number of cases**, with
>      replacement, from the majority class.
> 2. Induce a classification tree from the data **to maximum size, without pruning**. The tree is induced with the CART algorithm, with the
>      following modification: At each node, instead of searching through all
>      variables for the optimal split, **only search through a set of mtry
>      randomly selected variables**.
> 3. Repeat the two steps above for the number of times desired. Aggregate the predictions of the ensemble and make the final
>      prediction

My question is whether there is a way to implement such a model using the hyperparameters of the existing DRF model in `h2o` (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/drf.html).
My thought is that setting the hyperparameters of the `h2o` DRF model as:

```
balance_classes = False
fold_assignment = stratified     (though I wish there were some "unbalanced classes" option)
stopping_rounds = 0              (to force max size (I don't think h2o DRFs have pruning options))
mtries = -1                      (the article did not seem to recommend any ideal "mtry" size)
sample_rate_per_class = 0.5, 0.5
binomial_double_trees = True     (just because, I don't really think it affects the BRF alg.)
```

would be the thing to do. For many of the other hyperparameters, I'd probably just use whatever `h2o flow` UI recommends as the default values.

Does this look like it would work at approximating the BRF alg. described? Should I add (or remove) any other specific hyperparameter settings? Advice would be appreciated.

** Note: I have seen the other post on SO with similar questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618685/balanced-random-forest-in-r, [Implementing Balanced Random Forest (BRF) in R using RandomForests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/171380/167299)), but I believe this is different as it is not a package recommendation question, but rather asking about implementation in a specific framework.